# Как получить текущую дату в swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

Делаю приложение,которое должно выдавать данные в зависимости от даты. Например, сегодня 22 августа и погода выдается только на это число. Как связать приложение с датой и временем в swift?

Answer (score 5):

текущая дата

```
let date = NSDate()
```

а если хочешь "поиграться" с датой то смотри

```
NSDateFormatter()
```

вот ссылочка, познакомишься  с форматированием дат не помешает.

> http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nsdateformatter/

Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я делал вот так:

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

Удачи!

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

**Код:**

```
var time = NSDate()
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)            // указатель временной зоны относительно гринвича
var formatteddate = formatter.string(from: time as Date)
dateTimeLabel.text = "\(formatteddate)z"
```

**Отобразит дату и время в виде:**

24.09.2020 00:06:28z

Либо можно использовать переменную **time** для других задач.

Answer (score -1):

Чтоб получить текущее время, используй:

```
  let timestamp: NSNumber = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
  if let seconds = timestamp.doubleValue{
       let timestampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)
       let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:MM:SS a"

       timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timestampDate)
  }
```